# How to print boolean value in Go?

Tags: boolean, go

As we have `%d` for int. What is the format specifier for boolean values?

Comment: Try a code example: https://play.golang.org/p/RDGQEryOLP

Comment: Note that [`strconv.FormatBool(b)` is *much* faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552803/how-to-convert-a-bool-to-a-string-in-go) in case speed is important.

Answer (score 289):

If you use `fmt` package, you need `%t` format syntax, which will print `true` or `false` for boolean variables.

See package's [reference](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) for details.

Comment: Also note that the %v format will print a reasonable default string for any value.

Comment: If I try to take input a boolean value; any value starting from 't' is true and any other value is false.

Comment: package main

import fmt "fmt"

func main(){
        var flag bool
        fmt.Scanf("%t",&flag)
        fmt.Printf("%t",flag)
}

Comment: @Anuj Verma: When scanning input, `fmt.Scanf` had to deal somehow with any string you pass it. It can read values `true` and `false` correctly, and that's its main purpose. When it doesn't see neither `true`, nor `false` in the input, it goes another way: it takes only first character and returns `true` if it is 't' or `false` if it is anything else, i.g. not-'t'. Note, that the rest of the input is still available for scanning with other options. For example, try [such](http://pastebin.com/2EqrRFJg) code and check results with different inputs.

Answer (score 36):

`%t` is the answer for you.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   s := true
   fmt.Printf("%t", s)
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Use `%t` to format a boolean as `true` or `false`.

Comment: This is a the same answer, but shortened of the accepted one, remember that if you want to answer you should check when you can add something the post does not contains

Comment: this answer shows what will be in the output. Super!

Answer (score 3):

Some other options:

```
package main
import "strconv"

func main() {
   s := strconv.FormatBool(true)
   println(s == "true")
}
```

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var s string
   // example 1
   s = fmt.Sprint(true)
   println(s == "true")
   // example 2
   s = fmt.Sprintf("%v", true)
   println(s == "true")
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprint
- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprintf
- https://golang.org/pkg/strconv#FormatBool

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need the bool to be 0/1. Then, this works.

```golang
func b2int(b bool) int8 {
    if b { return 1 }
    return 0
}
fmt.Sprintf("%d", b2int(b))
```

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on the above answers to include types booleans.

To print standard bool use %t as mentioned above:

```
isItTrue = true

fmt.Printf("Is it true? %t", isItTrue)
```

To print typed bools use %v and dereference the variable:

```
var isItTrue bool = true

fmt.Printf("Is it true? %v", *isItTrue)
```