# How to convert a bool to a string in Go?

Tags: go, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `bool` called `isExist` to a `string` (`true` or `false`) by using `string(isExist)` but it does not work. What is the idiomatic way to do this in Go?

Comment: `strconv.FormatBool(t)` to set `true` to “true”. `strconv.ParseBool("true")` to set “true” to `true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

use the strconv package

[docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatBool)

`strconv.FormatBool(v)`

> func FormatBool(b bool) string FormatBool returns "true" or "false"
>   according to the value of b

Answer (score 48):

The two main options are:

1. [`strconv.FormatBool(bool) string`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatBool)
2. [`fmt.Sprintf(string, bool) string`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) with the `"%t"` or `"%v"` formatters.

Note that `strconv.FormatBool(...)` is *considerably* faster than `fmt.Sprintf(...)` as demonstrated by the following benchmarks:

```
func Benchmark_StrconvFormatBool(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    strconv.FormatBool(true)  // => "true"
    strconv.FormatBool(false) // => "false"
  }
}

func Benchmark_FmtSprintfT(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    fmt.Sprintf("%t", true)  // => "true"
    fmt.Sprintf("%t", false) // => "false"
  }
}

func Benchmark_FmtSprintfV(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    fmt.Sprintf("%v", true)  // => "true"
    fmt.Sprintf("%v", false) // => "false"
  }
}
```

Run as:

```
$ go test -bench=. ./boolstr_test.go 
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
Benchmark_StrconvFormatBool-8       2000000000           0.30 ns/op
Benchmark_FmtSprintfT-8             10000000           130 ns/op
Benchmark_FmtSprintfV-8             10000000           130 ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  3.531s
```

Answer (score 13):

In efficiency is not too much of an issue, but genericity is, just use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", isExist)`, as you would for almost all the types.

Answer (score 10):

you may use `strconv.FormatBool` like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    isExist := true
    str := strconv.FormatBool(isExist)
    fmt.Println(str)        //true
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", str) //"true"
}
```

or you may use `fmt.Sprint` like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    isExist := true
    str := fmt.Sprint(isExist)
    fmt.Println(str)        //true
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", str) //"true"
}
```

or write like `strconv.FormatBool`:

```
// FormatBool returns "true" or "false" according to the value of b
func FormatBool(b bool) string {
    if b {
        return "true"
    }
    return "false"
}
```